# How do I organize tables for simple lottery game? mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am building a simple lottery web game that will let users pick a number that is in between that weeks given range. A number will be randomly select to determine the winner. I have a table for users (id, username, password, pin, funds) but as I go to setup the games table I get kinda stumped. How do I keep track of what numbers have been picked so far and who they belong to? game (id, date, winner...)? How do I handle the fact that the number range can change from week to week?

**users**

- id
- username
- password
- pin
- funds

**games**

- id
- date
- winner

**number_range**

- date
- range

**selected_numbers**

- date
- user_id
- number

Is this heading in the right direction?

Comment: Can you add `games` table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create another table to store the number range each week (store the date and range) and then another table to store the user's selection (store the user id, date, and chosen number).

Comment: Do you think it might be better to use game_id instead of date in the tables number_range and selected_number since the games may not be a regular intervals?

Comment: You could do that, but if there is only one range chosen per game then the date becomes your ID effectively. If you ever wanted to do more than one game on a given day, then using an ID would be a better bet.